# eventConfigureTomcat Access to Config.groovy

Tags: grails

Grails 2.5.0

I'm defining an alternate context root via _Events.groovy using the eventConfigureTomcat closure. To do this, I've got code like so..

```
eventConfigureTomcat = { tomcat ->
  def newContextRoot = "/"
  def newContextPath = new File("/full/path/to/context/root")
  // more code below that doesn't matter for this question...
}
```

For the `newContextPath` I want to pull that value from my `Config.groovy` (which is actually pulling it from an external config file). I've tried using `grails.util.Holders` but it doesn't seem to be wired up at this specific event yet. Is this possible?

Answer (score 0):

You can set the value from your `Config.groovy` as an environment variable and then use it in `_Events.groovy`. If you still need to pull from an external config file, run a bash script inside of `.bashrc/.bashprofile` (wherever you define the environment variable).

```
eventConfigureTomcat = { tomcat ->
  String altctxroot = System.getenv("ALT_CTX_ROOT")
  def newContextRoot = "/"
  def newContextPath = new File("$altctxroot")
}
```